# How to tell iPhoneX or 8/7/6

Tags: titanium

I have tried to tell iPhoneX from otheres.

I use

`Ti.Platform.displayCaps`, but it shows the same values as iPhone X /6/7/8.

Even these two are supposed to have defferent screen size.

How can I check the screen size of iPhone X ??

```
[INFO]  Ti.Platform.displayCaps.density: xhigh
[INFO]  Ti.Platform.displayCaps.dpi: 480
[INFO]  Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight: 667
[INFO]  Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth: 375
[INFO]  Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have iPhone X splash screen and build app with with min TiSdk 6.3.0 ( require xCode 9 )

then

```
[INFO]  Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight: 812
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helper function to check if the device in question is an iPhone X.

```
function isiPhoneX() {
    return Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth === 375 && Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight === 812 && Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor === 3;
}
```